# Laravel 5.4 Passport on AWS Server 500 internal error Personal Access Token

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-passport

I'm trying to run Laravel 5.4 Passport on AWS Elastic Beanstalk PHP server. I followed the tutorial at https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-3/episodes/13 and succeeded generating a personal access token on my local computer.

However, when I `eb deploy` to the server, I tried to create a personal access token but it says
[image]

Comment: Expand this console post request and post what you are passing to the header and post fields.

Comment: its more likely a server side error. 
Can you share your storage/log/laravel.log file